# JSON: NSString stringWithContentsOfURL... with null in stream, crashes

Tags: ios, json, parsing, nsstring, nsnull

Environment: iOS 4.3+ using Xcode 4.3+

I'm always getting an iOS/Xcode crash when I implement the following string that returns data with nulls in it:

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]; 
NSDictionary *myResult =  (NSDictionary *)[myString JSONValue];
```

The result:

```
-[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17315e8
```

When the data stream contains no nulls (mostly), it works fine.
Is this a known problem?

Any remedy?

Comment: you can put a check before : NSDictionary *myResult = (NSDictionary *)[myString JSONValue]; e.g. NSDictionary *myResult =nil; if([myString length]>0){myResult = (NSDictionary *)[myString JSONValue];}

Comment: The code that you posted doesn't make sense. And you seem to use a library without telling us which one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix the data coming in from the source.  In almost all of my web service interaction, I use COALESCE on queries and SP's to make sure that the data coming out is always consistent.

Comment: That's an interesting idea... for the server (Oracle or otherwise).
It's best to supply CLEAN data.